# How can I update the first of many duplicate records in my SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this so far:

```
UPDATE A
SET DefaultContact = 1
FROM [StatementsDB].[dbo].[tblSupplierContact] A
INNER JOIN (SELECT B.FK_SupplierID
FROM [StatementsDB].[dbo].[tblSupplierContact] B
INNER JOIN [StatementsDB].[dbo].[tblSupplier] C ON B.FK_SupplierID = C.SupplierID
WHERE C.FK_ClientID = 3
GROUP BY B.FK_SupplierID) D ON A.FK_SupplierID = D.FK_SupplierID
```

So set the default contact as 1 where the `SupplierID` from `tblSupplierContact` matches to join's `SupplierID`. However, I need to only update one of the duplicate records in `tblSupplierContact`, not each one.

An example looks like this:

```
FK_SupplierID   Email   DefaultContact
    1           Email1  0
    1           Email2  0
    1           Email3  0
    1           Email4  0
```

So lets say I only want to update the first one of these duplicate records. I have gotten so far, I just don't know how to do the last part.

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Non ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: @jarlh My bad, I've added it. Im using SQL Server

Comment: Did you tried update top(1) ?

Comment: @SrinivasV. Yes, it only updates one record when I actually need to update the whole data set. There a multiple duplicates in the whole dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example of an updateable CTE:

```
DECLARE @tblTest TABLE(FK_SupplierID INT,Email VARCHAR(100),DefaultContact BIT);
INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES
 (1,'Email1',0)
,(1,'Email2',0)
,(1,'Email3',0)
,(1,'Email4',0)
,(2,'Email1',0)
,(2,'Email2',0)
,(2,'Email3',0)
,(2,'Email4',0);

WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT --choose an order by clause, if the choice should not be random...
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FK_SupplierID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nr 
          ,* 
    FROM @tblTest
)
UPDATE Numbered SET DefaultContact = 1 WHERE Nr = 1;

SELECT * FROM @tblTest;
```